# React Tic Tac Toe, Array.slice(), Mutability

Tags: reactjs

In react tic tac toe [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), why they had to use Array.slice()?

```
handleClick(i) {
 const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
 squares[i] = 'X';
 this.setState({squares: squares});
}
```

They change the **state.squares** anyway right? Trying to understand whats going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a common way create a new array and copy all elements to it. This is to pass **new** Array to `setState` and not mutate the old one - which would not cause the component to re-render.

a New array will cause re-render. If you had mutated the array like:

```
this.props.squares[i] = 'X';
```

react would not be notified that something had changed in the state.

Comment: Won't resetting state with new array re render?

Comment: Great. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mutate the state directly, so when you write

```
handleClick(i) {
 const squares = this.state.squares.slice(); // you are creating a new copy of the squared array,
 squares[i] = 'X';
 this.setState({squares: squares});
}
```

Any changes that you make on the cloned state is not reflected on the original state.

Mutation is specially troublesome when you wish to use lifecycle methods and compare prevState and currentState, for instance, if you set state like

```
handleClick(i) {
 const squares = this.state.squares;
 squares[i] = 'X';
 this.setState({squares: squares});
}
```

In this case say, in `componentDidUpdate` function, you want to take an action based on a change in squares array,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if(nextState.squares !== this.state.squares) {
      // do something here
   }
}
```

In the above case the comparison will fail since the `prevState` and `this.state` will return you the same result as you mutated the original state.

Also calling `setState` is necessary to cause a re-render